# How to get correct index in datagrid after double clicking heading to sort?

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, xaml, datagrid

My current problem is: I get a datagrid at first, then when I select a row, I'll have a index, with that index, I could use convert datagrid to DataTable DataTable.rows[idx]["Column Name"] to get the value. When I double click the header again, everything is resorted, at the backend, the datagrid is not refreshed, when I get the new index, it will go to the old datagrid to find the new index value. I don't want to refresh the datatable every time, too much calculation.

Forexample, the first row, after resorting, the index become 4, the system will go to use DataTable.rows[4]["Column Name"] to get a value, which isn't the value I want.

Thank you so much!

Comment: When you sort. a row could well lose focus and change colour or disappear because it's now off the screen. Selection isn't going to change though. You select the row ( or item ) not the index.  Why are you using index rather than selecteditem?

Comment: I don't have a class for that datagrid. Without a class, how can I use selecteditems to get the detail?

Comment: A window is a partial class with the xaml in one file and code in another. So technically, i think you do have a class. You can reference the selecteditems of a datagrid in code behind.

Comment: Thanks for your response, what do you mean reference the selecteditems of a datagrid? I use SQLDataAdapter to fill a dataset, then get a datagrid, which class should I use to get the IList?

Comment: The code behind of your window. Use the datagrid's selecteditems property. From the documentation, note the inheritance from MultiSelector. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.controls.datagrid?view=netframework-4.8 which has SelectedItems https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.controls.primitives.multiselector.selecteditems?view=netframework-4.8

Comment: Note that working with a datatable and casting rows[n].Items[nn] is widely considered bad practice. Much more usual to use an orm such as entity framework. Even then, translating data from dto into viewmodels and binding itemssource to an observablecollection of viewmodels is more usual.

Answer (score 0):

The SelectedIndex property gets changed only when a row is selected by user's action or by code. So even after sorting, the property's value doesn't get changed.
You can explicitly reset it to -1 (to select nothing) or 0 (for selecting the first row) in the SortCommand event.

Comment: Sorry I didn't express clearly, my current problem is: I get a datagrid at first, then when I select a row, I'll have a index, with that index, I could use datagrid->datatable.rows[idx]["Column Name"] to get the value. When I double click the header again, everything is resorted,  at the backend, the datagrid is not refreshed, when I get the new index, it will go to the old datagrid to find the new index value. I don't want to refresh the datatable every time, too much calculation, is there a way to solve that? Thank you so much!!

Answer (score 0):

Currently I convert the datagrid to datatable each time when the selection changed.

```
        private void DataGrid1_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        var idx = DataGrid1.SelectedIndex;


        _dtDataGrid = ((DataView)DataGrid1.ItemsSource).ToTable();



        if (idx < 0) idx = 0;
        BindAmDetail(_dtDataGrid, idx);
        if (DataGrid1.SelectedItem != null) DataGrid1.ScrollIntoView(DataGrid1.SelectedItem);


    }
```